# Reactjs sliding animation sliding panel

Tags: reactjs

I have a dripdrowns...once d last drop down is selected I'll be displaying some content, for that toggling I want to add some beautiful animations. Is there any react related things to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
sidebarToggle(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.body.classList.toggle('sidebar-hidden');
  }
  
  <a className="nav-link navbar-toggler sidebar-toggler" onClick={this.sidebarToggle} href="#">&#9776;</a>
```

You can do like this
It will show button and on clicking that button will toggle sidebar kind of animation from the left